# Why does the Spring application save logs in two places?

Tags: spring-boot, logback

When the application is started (spring-boot), the application saves the logs from the console in two places. How to change it?

This is a multi-module application, and this is the configuration of one of the modules.

pom.xml:

```
...
<properties>
    <logs.path>${basedir}/logs</logs.path>
</properties>
...
```

application.yml:

```
...
logging.path: @logs.path@
...
```

logback.xml:

```
<configuration>

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight(%-5level) %magenta([%thread]) %logger{36}.%M: %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="CONSOLE_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/console.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/console/console.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36}.%M: %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_FILE"/>
</root>

</configuration>
```

When I run the application logs are saved in the following locations:

modules/LOG_PATH_IS_UNDEFINED/console.log

and

modules/singleModule/logs/console.log

How to fix it.

Comment: For one thing, you should define the environment variable or system property `LOG_PATH` so it provides a useful path. Maybe set it to `singleModule`?

Comment: The logs.path (pom.xml) variable is set in all single modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the  tag, where I specified the application.yml file. It helped:

```
<configuration>

<property resource="application.yml" />

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight(%-5level) %magenta([%thread]) %logger{36}.%M: %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="CONSOLE_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${logging.path}/console.log</file>
...
```

The application.yml and logback.xml files are located in the resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `logging.path` from application.yml and check if `LOG_PATH` variable is properly set.